# Appengine and java.io usage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, io

I want to read the contents of a file present in the war directory, in this case, the file contains lat,long values for each bus route. 
how can i read the file the contents of the file ? fileinputstream throws security exception. is there any other way to read the contents of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use all functionalities of  java.io classes from google appengine.  You can check [this link](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-java-io/).

Google applications states this as below ;

*An application cannot write to the file system. An app can read files, but only
 files  uploaded with the application code. The app must use the App Engine datastore, 
memcache or  other services for all data that persists between requests.*

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can use java.io to read files stored with the application, you just cannot write to files from within App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the war, you should be able to access it through the getResourceAsStream method of ServletContext.

This is the standard way to access a resource from the war in any web app, whether it's deployed on app engine or not, BTW.